# How to get drawable item by resource id in kotlin programmatically?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have xml file in drawable folder.
How can i get this item from activity class in kotlin and set on click listener?

My part of code from @drawable/delete_bg

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/delete_btn"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_trash"
        android:bottom="60dp"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="60dp"
        android:top="10dp"
        />
```

i've tried to use findViewById and getDrawable but this didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the below

```
val drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.delete_bg, theme)
```

```
val drawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(applicationContext, R.drawable.delete_bg)
```